# XSLT JavaScript Entity Validation Error

Tags: javascript, xslt, entity

i've pasted my full xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" >
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

            <!-- Create a Jobs array        -->
            <script type="text/javascript">

                var jobs = {
                <xsl:for-each select="jobs/job">
                        "<xsl:value-of select='ID'/>" : "<xsl:value-of select='Title'/>", 
                </xsl:for-each>     
                        "0000" : "Test"  // Stop IE8 error message
                };
            </script>   

 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

This results in the following javascript in my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">

    var jobs = {

                "J123456" : "Teacher - & Blah Blah",                
                "0000" : "Test"  // Stop IE8 error message
    };
</script>
```

but the & sign is causing w3c validation failure.  How do i output it as amp; ?

Comment: Can you please add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: We need to know whether you want to create HTML 4 or HTML5 or XHTML, so we need to see whether you use any namespaces for your result elements and how your `xsl:output` elements look like exactly. Is the HTML you create as the XSLT result sent to the browser as text/html or as some XML (e.g. application/xml)?

Comment: This is a pure guess on my part, but given the fact that your error message is talking about delimiters, and your code looks like this: `"<xsl:value-of select="Title"/>"` , I would at the very least try to change the inner quotes to single quotes: `"<xsl:value-of select='Title'/>"`

Comment: hi @MartinHonnen  i've included my full code.

Comment: hi @bjimba i've tried single inner quotes but it still doesn't fix my issue

Comment: While an XSLT stylesheet can create a single `script` element as its output I don't see how you would validate that as HTML or XHTML as I think the validator would need a complete HTML document structure to do any meaningful validation. So how does a minimal HTML document you create with XSLT and try to validate look like? Are you trying to do HTML validation or XHTML validation when getting the complaint about the ampersand `&`?

Comment: Browsers are very forgiving of dealing with `&` inside `script` elements since a regular XML parser may complain about invalid entity.  And if the intent of the document is to be processed by a browser, trying to output `&amp;` instead may lead to JavaScript errors.